# iOS Crash Reporter Service / Alternative to MacDevCrashReports.com

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, crash, report

I'm looking for a iOS crash reporter web service. I know [MacDevCrashReports](http://macdevcrashreports.com/) but they currently do not accept new sign ups.

I know there is a open source crash reporter framework on GitHub, but I don't want to put that stuff on a server, configure it and so on. A nice web service would be much nicer.

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 8):

I've been using [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) for my iOS and Android apps.  It's saved me a LOT of time.  It has a few more features than BugSense and Hoptoad.

Answer (score 6):

[MacDevCrashReports](http://macdevcrashreports.com/) is running out, since I am not able to continue providing the service for free, the amount of data is just too huge. 100.000 crash reports e.g. require about 2GB of storage. BUT I am working on a new service with some friends to provide enhanced functionality for managing crash reports and other developer related data. You might want to check for [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/) for news about that.

Until then, you can also use the source [MacDevCrashReports](http://macdevcrashreports.com/) is based on, on your own web server. It is completely open source and available at [GitHub](http://github.com/therealkerni/crashreporterdemo/).

The process of collecting crashes is using [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). Which is more reliable and is async-safe. There are also cases of crashes, like crashes in objc runtime, where it will result in a deadlock (Information by Landon Fuller, creator of [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/)).

Symbolication of [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) created crash log files, can be done with the dSYM bundles, check [this description](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo/wiki/Remote-symbolication).

Regarding the AppStore argument from Peter. As Patrick points out, this is not working for Ad-Hoc builds, which is one big issue, since you want to find and fix the crashes while testing. On the other side, the crash reports in iTunes Connect are very inaccurate:

- The data set only updates once a day
- The data is only available after users sync their devices with iTunes and only IF they agreed sending that data. Since most users don't understand the dialog, they deny
- You only get a subset of crashes, the top 5
- You don't get instant reports, as opposed using an in-app reporter
- You don't get grouping of similar crashes as the web service does
- You don't get a web interface to work with the crashes, make notes, mark as fixed, etc.

iTunes connect reports for my app to have 0 (zero) crashes, but in my database there are about 200! Check this [blog post](http://www.futuretap.com/blog/where-to-3-0-5-and-the-truth-about-itunes-connect-crash-reports/) by [futuretap](http://www.futuretap.com/) about their experience and findings of using an in-app crash reporter.

Comment: most of the links have expired !

Answer (score 3):

There is a new service called [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com) . Give it a shot!

Comment: And it gets better every day. Try rev3.

Comment: It really sucks. WP7/WP8 api is unusable. Most of graphs on their website are in "coming soon" state.

Answer (score 2):

For ad-hoc crash reports you can use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/). It has TestFlights [SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/), using which you can collect crash reports and additional data, checkpoints, feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're distributing through the App Store, you should get crash reports in iTunes Connect.

Comment: You're right. But I would also like to get crash reports for AdHoc distributed beta builds.

Comment: The problem is that they aren't real-time and only include users that have synced up their phones to itunes.

Comment: @Julie: Let's hope that changes in iOS 5. It might be worth filing a bug about it, just to make sure they know about that obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

We're playing around with [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com) for some apps. Looks to work pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [HockeyApp](http://www.hockeyapp.net/) and [Crashlytics](http://beta.crashlytics.com/) with great success.  HockeyApp is nice in that once you've added your IPA file to their service they even provide a download page for you to distribute your build to your testers.

Crashlytics is a little cleaner from a UX perspective but it's still in beta and has a bit of a wait period whereas HockeyApp you can use immediately and it's a bit more mature. It also seems Crashlytics gives preference to apps that are already in the app store when you sign up for the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check out [BugHD](http://bughd.com),support iOS,Mac & Android Crash Report

Answer (score 0):

For tracking crashes, I really like [Appsee for iOS](https://www.appsee.com/ios-analytics/?cpnid=7010N000000hv6x) (although also great for Android apps). It gives detailed crash reports, and also session recordings that let you visually monitor all crashes within your app.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Appsee.start() 
    return true
}
```