# Tracking crashes on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging

i would like to do the following, do you know if it is possible?:

When my app crashes (for whatever reason and at whichever point) i want a method to be called that sends some data to my server (for example, the method where it crashed, at what time,etc)

Is this possible? Can anyone provide some reference to accomplish this?

Basically what i want to do is that when i get a SIGABTR or EXC_BAD_ACCESS in my code is to send that data to my servers.

Thanks in advance,

Pablo

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/), an open source framework that lets you output protobuf-encoded messages that you can send to a server.  If you don't have a server (or are lazy like me), you can use [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com).  I've been using them for both my Android and ios apps.

Comment: I've noticed you're mentioning Crittercism quite a bit.  It seems to me that you're affiliated with them.  If so, please state it openly as a disclaimer or something.

Comment: i'm not affiliated with them but one of my friends works there!

Answer (score 1):

I use an open source framework called [QuincyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit). Has worked really well for me so far.

Comment: The framework has been renamed to QuincyKit: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit I absolutely recommend it, especially since we found that iTunes Connect Crash Reports totally suck: http://www.futuretap.com/blog/where-to-3-0-5-and-the-truth-about-itunes-connect-crash-reports/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know of is [CrashKit](https://github.com/kaler/CrashKit), but it hasn't been updated in almost a year.

Answer (score 0):

You should get crash reports in iTunes Connect when your App is available on the AppStore. Other than that, there are some alternatives, check out this similar question: [iOS Crash Reporter Service / Alternative to MacDevCrashReports.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907651/ios-crash-reporter-service-alternative-to-macdevcrashreports-com)